# My Skype keeps on crashing when I run Skype and try to login

Tags: crash, skype

Skype will crash after I run it for a few seconds. This problem causes me to be unable to login to Skype. I am running Windows 7. The following is the problem signature.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Skype.exe
  Application Version:  5.3.0.113
  Application Timestamp:    4dd67601
  Fault Module Name:    Skype.exe
  Fault Module Version: 5.3.0.113
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4dd67601
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 006ebe12
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    17417
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: Hum, i guess it's kind of normal right now, Skype mentions a problem (again) on their twitter : https://twitter.com/#!/skype/status/73718207676022784

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a bug and poorly tested Skype Upgrade.

I am not aware of the exact issue, but Nick Craver just posted on Twitter about this and a solution.

["#Skype Delete or rename C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Skype\shared.xml to make it run again"](http://twitter.com/#!/derFunk/statuses/73728536694882304)

In response to something I wrote to him, he wrote ["the deleting works...looks like a (poorly tested) infrastructure change that the client can't handle at all, bad node data saved"](http://twitter.com/#!/Nick_Craver/statuses/73743243875061760)

So, not tested myself, but I trust what he wrote! Do the above, or to make it simpler, copy the following in to either a run box, or explorer address bar:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Skype\
```

and delete the file named:

```
shared.xml
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug, which affected Skype on Windows, Linux and MacOS X.

Solution is to delete `shared.xml` from your settings directory. Skype has provided detailed instructions:

> **Windows Vista and Windows 7**
>
> 1. Close Skype.
>
>    - Right-click
>        the Skype icon in the system tray (at
>
>      ### the bottom right of the screen)
>
>    Choose Quit.
> 2. Ensure that “Show
>      hidden files and folders” is switched
>      on.
>
>    - Click Start, type run and
>        press Enter.
>    - Type control
>        folders and click OK.
>    - Select the
>        View tab and ensure relevant entry is
>        enabled.
> 3. Locate the shared.xml
>      file.
>
>    - Click Start, type run and
>        press Enter.
>    - Type
>
>      ### `%appdata%\skype` and click OK.
>
>    Delete the `shared.xml` file.
> 4. Restart Skype. The `shared.xml` file
>      will be recreated.
>
> **Windows XP**
>
> 1. Close Skype.
>
>    - Right-click
>        the Skype icon in the system tray (at
>        the bottom right of the screen)
>    - Choose Quit.
> 2. Ensure that “Show
>      hidden files and folders” is switched
>      on.
>
>    - Click Start and then Run…
>    - Type control folders and click OK.
>    - Select the View tab and ensure
>        relevant entry is enabled.
> 3. ### Locate the `shared.xml` file.
>
>    Click Start and then Run…
>
>    - Type `%appdata%\skype` and click OK.
>    - Delete the `shared.xml` file.
> 4. Restart Skype. The `shared.xml` file
>      will be recreated.
>
> **Mac OS X**
>
> 1. Quit Skype.
> 2. Go to the folder `~/Library/Application Support/Skype/`
> 3. Delete the file `shared.xml` (it will be recreated once you open Skype
>      again, this is fine).
> 4. Start Skype.

I'm using **Linux**, so for me it was:

1. quit Skype
2. `rm ~/.Skype/shared.xml`
3. start Skype

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the latest version. Try, as I will, to see if Wil's post offers some success; but if not, download an older version from [OldApps](http://www.oldapps.com/skype.php) - I've been running 5.1 (reputedly one of the most stable recent versions) for several weeks now.